# Unity exported game : VSync issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, vsync

I'm making a game in Unity, the project was doing fine but I wanted to create a build of the game just to see how it goes and it seems that there is a little vsync problem on the build which was not visible in the unity editor.

Here is a video that shows the problem :
https://youtube.com/shorts/JCzZcsVj3t0?feature=share

I've tried to run the game on an external screen (144Hz), but I don't know why, the problem is **not visible** at all !?!!
Maybe the problem is on my laptop's screen (60Hz), but as I said in the beginning, this vsync problem does not appear in the editor (also not in "real" games).

My pc is a HP Victus 16, does anybody knows what's happenig ?

Edit : I've tried to record a video from the laptop itself (which corresponds to the screen with the problem) but the problem is not visible on the recorded video ...

Thanks :D !

Comment: Video it on your phone recording the screen?

Comment: The video is a record from my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution but **I don't know why it works** ...

I've changed the default rendering pipeline to [HDRP](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.1/manual/Upgrading-To-HDRP.html) and the problem is gone, there is no more VSync problem.